# Is there a way to calculate balances of products between countries?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, optimization

I created a dataset with the capacity and production of a product per country.

I am interested in calculating the balances between these different countries.
For example, France has a positive balance of 50, Belgium a balance of 10, and Germany a balance of -50.

I am interested in creating a PyQGIS function that calculates balances between these countries based on the distance to optimize these flows; E.G: Germany to Belgium 10, Germany to France 40, equilibrium reached! Are there any existing functions of which I am not familiar with?

```
output_folder = 'C:/Users/*/Desktop/Extr-act/Output/'
layer5 = QgsVectorLayer(output_folder + "Distance matrix.shp", "Distance matrix", "ogr")
layer6 = QgsVectorLayer(output_folder + "Centroids.shp", "Centroids", "ogr")

with edit(layer6):
    for f in layer6.getFeatures():
        if f["BC_Balance"] < 0:
            for i in layer5.getFeatures():
                if f["CNTR_CODE"] == i["InputID"]:

                    f["Dest"] = ["InputID"]
                    f["Amount"] = 0
            layer5.updateFeature(f)
```

I have added the question with the code I came up with so far.

[image]
[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WCllWC2dgSCsqQ3TokB9obO90jd4ZAoT?usp=sharing

Comment: I am just asking if anyone has an idea of where to start

Comment: It seems like your problem can be broken into two pieces. First, figuring out the distances between countries, and then second working in the trade portion. Another piece you need to consider is how the countries will impact each other via shared neighbors. For example, in your France-Belgium-Germany example above, what happens when you get to Poland and Austria - will they change Germany situation? Or would Spain's interaction with France impact how France interacts with Germany? Consider if this might require multiple iterations over each country, rather than a single pass.

Comment: @ycartwhelen you are right, it will probably take multiple iterations. I created a distance matrix for distances between centroids of countries so I can loop through these distances and calculate balances. Do you have any tips where I can find a start on this function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know QGIS well enough to suggest specific tools. If you edit your original post to include these details on what you've tried so far it might help other people provide better answers.

Comment: @BERA I tried to edit my post according to the requests, do you understand my question better now?

Comment: updated shapefiles are not allowed on the platform? If not, I don't think I know how to create a data frame.

Comment: Like the centroids table, with BC_balance_new, assigned_country and amount_to_country added. So the columns would look like: CNTR_CODE, time_2019, BC_balance, BC_balance_new, assigned_country, amount_to_assigned_country

Comment: @BERA Do you still want to look at a possible solution?

Comment: @ycartwhelen could maybe come up with something after the added information?

Comment: No to much work. You could ask this as a pandas question on stackoverflow.